# Java work with JFrame and JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have this package

gui

```
  --Gui.java (JFrame)
  --Game.java (JPanel)
```

and I want open JPanel(Hra) from JFrame(Gui) after I press button, my code looks like

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // connect:
    this.setVisible(false);
    new Hra().setVisible(true);
}
```

but when I start Gui and I press button, the program doesn't work and program is still running.

Thank you for answer

Comment: So your code creates a new JPanel, adds it to nothing, sets it visible, and expects it to be displayed. Swing doesn't work that way as JPanels and other components must be added to a top-level window in order to be displayed. It looks like you're guessing at this, and I can speak from experience by telling you that you shouldn't guess at this stuff as you'll invariably guess wrong. Google and read the tutorials as they'll not lead you wrong.

Comment: @hovercraft-full-of-eels I was looking for some tuts, but no one tell me anythink, do u have some good tuts for my problrm? I need go in Jform to Jpanel and i still don't know how do that...

Comment: The best tutorials are a click away. Hover over the [tag:swing] and click on the info link, and there you'll find all the tutorials you'll need for now on creating Swing GUI's. Go into the [Swing Tutorials link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and check out the using components subsection on use of JPanels and JFrames. Also check out the layout manager tutorials for how to put these things together. Look at the sample programs that you can find associated with each tutorial.

Comment: @hovercraft-full-of-eels when I use JFrame it works. But I think is not optimal

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

You have just initialized the jpanel. You would need to add it to the jframe as well:

Untested Code:
    //Assuming this button is directly added on the frame

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    this.getContentPane().add(new Hra());
    this.pack();

}
```

Comment: What is the "f" ? It's class or?

Comment: Better to use a CardLayout to swap views perhaps.

Comment: I agree, CardLayout makes the navigation easier and cleaner. But the OP question was more specific to adding JPanel :)

Comment: ... and is wrong because the original poster doesn't know any better. He's making wild guesses here.

Comment: Well its presumptuous to say something like that. CardLayout may be an overkill for the OP's purpose may be just using something simple like SplitPane might get the job done, you don't know! How can you recommend something like that without knowing the requirement. Just my opinion